# Pygame rect object rotation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am using python 2.7.9 and pygame 1.9.2. Here is the relevant code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame, sys
from math import *
from decimal import *

while 1:
    ...
    deg = (atan2(Decimal(y), Decimal(x)))*180/pi
    pygame.transform.rotate(surf, deg)
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    print deg
    clock.tick(60)
```

Why isn't pygame.transform.rotate working? Printing the angle using math.acos has no problem, but I just can't seem to figure out how to rotate the rect object. I tried taking out *180/pi to use radians, but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
surf = pygame.transform.rotate(surf, deg)
```

The [`pygame.transform.rotate` method](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) seems to *return* a rotated object rather than rotating its coordinates in place.

Comment: can you give me an example?